# Run the "Clean Up" Right-Click Menu Action Using Shell Script

Tags: macos, finder, snap-to-grid

all.

Using a shell script that can be triggered how I wish (BetterTouchTool), I want to run the "Clean Up" option from context menu that appears when I right-click on an empty space on the desktop. This simply rearranges all desktop icons so they snap to a grid square.

I've done some web-searching but all I got was auto-empty trash and archiving tricks.

If anyone knows how to do this, kindly let us know.

Thanks

Comment: Try adapting this maybe? https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/321809

Answer (score 0):

BetterTouchTool can do this easily with the "trigger context menu item"

Comment: Maybe you could expand and detail your answer to better understand your answer?

Comment: BetterTouchTool is a very popular application with lots of its own documentation. https://docs.bettertouchtool.net/